# PEAR Mail suddenly not working

Tags: php

I am using [PEAR Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail). It was working fine very nicely for many days, I just changed the redirect URL and suddenly it is not working. Please see the code below.
I am getting information through GET and SESSION from another website. It was working nicely but when I changed the redirect URL in the bottom mail is not going.
The "send" function is returning true, but no email received.

```
    <?php
session_start();
include("C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\\v5.4\pear\Mail.php");
    /* SMTP server name, port, user/passwd */
    $smtpinfo["host"] = "mail.abc.com.com";
    $smtpinfo["port"] = "25";
    $smtpinfo["auth"] = true;
    $smtpinfo["username"] = "support@abc.com";
    $smtpinfo["password"] = "xxxxxxx";
    /* Create the mail object using the Mail::factory method */
    $mail_object =& Mail::factory("smtp", $smtpinfo);
    $headers["From"] = "ABC Corp"."<support@abc.com>";
    $headers["MIME-Version"] = "1.0";
    $headers["Content-type"] = "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
    /* mail setup recipients, subject etc */

    if(isset($_GET['cdata']) && $_GET['ot']==3)
    {
        $mailmsg=urldecode($_GET['cdata']);
        $headers["Subject"] = "New Contact Info";
        $recipients = "aj@abc.com";
        $headers["To"] = "aj@abc.com";
    }
    if($_GET['ot']==1)
    {
        $mailmsg = urldecode("<b>Purchase Information</b>: ".$_SESSION['proid']."<br /><br /><hr />Sender Information:<br />".$_GET['si']."<br /><hr />Receiver Information:<br />".$_GET['ri']);
        $headers["Subject"] = "Order Information";
        $se1=$_GET['se'];
        $re1=$_GET['re'];
        $recipients = $se1.",".$re1.",aj@abc.com";
        $headers["To"] = $se1.",".$re1.",aj@abc.com";
    }
    if($_GET['ot']==2)
    {
        $mailmsg = urldecode("<b>Purchase Information</b>: <br />".$_SESSION['proid']."<br /><br /><hr /><b>Sender Information</b>:<br />".$_GET['si']."<br /><hr /><b>Receiver Information</b>: Same as above");   
        $headers["Subject"] = "Order Information";
        $se1=$_GET['se'];
        $recipients = $se1.",aj@abc.com";
        $headers["To"] = $se1.",aj@abc.com";
    }
    /* Ok send mail */

    $mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $mailmsg);
    header('Location:http://abc.com/cart.php?fin=1');
```

?>
I added this code at the bottom:

```
    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
        echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
    }
```

It is printing the "else" part.

BIG EDIT: Now it is showing this message:

> Failed to connect to mail.abc.com:25 [SMTP: Failed to connect socket:
>   An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its
>   access permissions. (code: -1, response: )]

Comment: Ya there is, please see the edit

Comment: Well your php is ok. It is a SMTP problem. Ask your network administrator.